# Route matching from static Uri + route data extract

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a .Net Core 2.2 MVC app with routes defined as route attributes on my MVC actions.
I would like to find the matching route (if any) and what the route data are from a given Uri (i.e. **not the current HTTP request but a static Uri coming from a database for instance**).

I already use the `LinkGenerator.GetPathByAction()` method to get the "route URL" for a specific action with route data. What I am after would be the opposite: **a method that takes a URL/Uri and return the matching route and its route data.**

For instance if I have a route registered with the following template:
`[Route("/my-action/{id:int}/{name}")]` 
the URL ***"/my-action/5/my-test-name"*** would return the following route data:

- id: 5
- name: my-test-name

I went through the routing documentation but I haven't found anything.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/routing.md

The only option that I see would be to somehow call the `RouteMiddleware` (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Routing/src/RouterMiddleware.cs) with a mock HttpContext which seems overkill if even doable?

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. "I would like to find the matching route (if any) and what the route data are from a given Uri". Can you explain further the context in which you want to get the matching route info? I ask because this info is available (to some extent) in different ways in different places.

Comment: Hi @gerryc.inc, I have a lot of complex routes defined in my application. At one point, I save the request URL in a database (i.e. /my-action/5/test) and although I have the route data at this stage, I don't save them.
Then later, I retrieve the local URL from the database. I would like to process it again (without having to make a new HTTP request) in order to get the matching route and the route data, effectively extracting the matching logic used by the RouteMiddleware.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to find the matching route (if any) and what the route data are from a given Uri.

If you want to get the route data in the action with the matching route , you could directly use `GetRouteData` in the current `HttpContext` object like below :

```
 [Route("/GetRouteData/{id:int}/{name}")]
 public void GetRouteData()
 {
        var routeData = HttpContext.GetRouteData();

        var routeCollection = routeData.Values;
        var id = routeData?.Values["id"]?.ToString();
        var name = routeData?.Values["name"]?.ToString();

  }
```

About finding out if a URL matches an action in ASP.NET MVC Core , you could refer to the following links :

https://joonasw.net/view/find-out-if-url-matches-action

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/May/15/Accessing-RouteData-in-an-ASPNET-Core-Controller-Constructor

https://rimdev.io/asp-net-core-routes-middleware/

Comment: Thanks but I would like the route data **from a given Uri not from the current context**. 
Imagine getting a URL/Uri from a database and trying to get the matching route (and route data) that you would otherwise get by actually processing it as a new HTTP request.